# ReferenceError: ChannelType is not defined

Tags: discord.js

I'm just starting out in this field and I'd like to know what's wrong with my lines.....

**Here's the error:**
`if (!channel || channel.type !== ChannelType.GuildText) {                                   ^ ReferenceError: ChannelType is not defined`

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jEfx.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfRRY.png)

Thank you for your reply......

I haven't tried anything yet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`ChannelType` is also part of the `discord.js` package, so in order to use it in your code, you need to destructure it the same way you did to `Events`.

```
const { Events, ChannelType } = require('discord.js');
```